# vs ignore name mangling of dll function

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll

i am working on a dll proxy project and using the following [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically?msg=5015136#xx5015136xx)
when i try work on a dll which has the following function name: 
_ap_abort_on_oom@0, after building the solution in visual studio 2013 its ignoring the "2" character and name the function in the new dll as: _ap_abort_on_oom

in my def file :
    EXPORTS
    _ap_abort_on_oom@0=**E__0** @1

here is an example of the difference using dllexp:

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: You just wrote it wrong, make it `E__0 = _ap_abort_on_oom@0 @1`

Comment: no, it should be like this because i work on dll proxy project